# Refresh Excel to see Other User Changes on Shared File using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know this been asked before but it seems no one was able to provide a real solution. As of right now Excel allows you to set a setting for Shared Workbooks to automatically Update Changes and see Other User changes every 5 minutes. I'm looking for a way to lower this to 1 minute or less. So, I was wondering if there is any VBA function/command to force through this Refresh from perhaps the click of a button? Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Your can take a look at these links

StackExchange Superuser - https://superuser.com/questions/440187/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-shared-spreadsheet-to-update-without-closing-and-reopeni

Microsoft Official documentation - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534?ocmsassetID=HP010342985&CTT=1&CorrelationId=5c14f8f1-c6b5-443c-82d2-c05abfc4b950&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Hope those will solve your problem !